# How to get particular cropping image using canvas circular image?

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas

[image]I am create a custom ImageView with Pinch IN-OUT zoom and circular crop image.The Pinch in-out is wroking fine but when i trying to cropping image, can't get the particulr circle image. I'm using Pinch in-out working based on onTuchListener and Circular Cropping based on canvas class.

I have used below mentioned code for Pinch in-out and Circle Crop image:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        onDrawReady = true;
        imageRenderedAtLeastOnce = true;
        if (delayedZoomVariables != null) {
            setZoom(delayedZoomVariables.scale, delayedZoomVariables.focusX, delayedZoomVariables.focusY, delayedZoomVariables.scaleType);
            delayedZoomVariables = null;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (bitmap == null) {
            circleWindowFrame(); //Creating circle view
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    protected void circleWindowFrame() {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.overlay));
        paint.setAlpha(99);
        osCanvas.drawRect(outerRectangle, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
        float centerX = getWidth() / 2;
        float centerY = getHeight() / 2;

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        float radius = width / 2;
        osCanvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, paint);
    }
```

This code for Cropping:

```
public static Bitmap getCrop() {
        Bitmap circleBitmap;
        circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
        c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Thanks for Advance...

Comment: https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView use this library for circular image

Comment: No,I need Circle crop image. **Please see attached image.**

Comment: did u check my answer

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 public static Bitmap toOvalBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap) {
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        int color = 0xff424242;
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);

        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
        canvas.drawOval(rect, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

        bitmap.recycle();

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: I need to crop the selected Overlay circular area. **But your example is cropping full image.**

Comment: did u use my method instead of yours getCrop() method?

Comment: in your question you said it is not cropping properly, what i did was a cropping method so i think it should work for you given the fact that your method was cropping the desired overlay area of the image

Comment: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper go have a look at this library althought you have to change some parameters to get the desired result but this will definitely help you out. Have Patience.

Comment: Bro,I added zoom functionality. So your method cropping full image. But I need cropping the highlighted area  Image after zoom-in and out.I know getCrop() is not working properly.

Comment: just look at the Github project i refer to you in last comment, it will surely have that zooming functionality.